# Pinterest - Download all pinned images

Tags: pinterest

Ive got a private instagram board with c. 2000 image pins on which i wish to download as JPEG / PNG etc.

If i click into each pin there is an option to download the image, but is there a way i can download all the pin images at once, either using an inbuilt Pinterest command, or a 3rd party tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using DownAlbum to download the pins : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downalbum/cgjnhhjpfcdhbhlcmmjppicjmgfkppok?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can check PinDown Free extension out for Chrome Browser. The free version has a limit of 250 photos per board.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pindown/flieckppkcgagklbnnhnkkeladdghogp

You can see more details on this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=179&v=DxKt9AwnKH8&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python recipe.
Credit goes to **awang**. [Source](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580611-batch-download-all-the-pinned-pictures-in-your-pin)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Batch download all the pinned pictures in your Pinterest board to a local folder.
Be noted: you have to keep your internet browser signed in your Pinterest account first.
Please contact me @ alfred.hui.wong@gmail.com if any question
@author: awang
"""
URL_PinterestBoard=input("Please enter your Pinterest board url starting with Http:// ")

from tkinter import filedialog
Folder_saved=filedialog.askdirectory(title="Select a local folder where you want to put all the pinned pictures")

from lxml import html
import requests

page=requests.get(URL_PinterestBoard)
tree=html.fromstring(page.content)

pins=tree.xpath('//div[@class="pinHolder"]//@href')

del page, tree

import requests, bs4
import urllib

n=1
for singlePin in pins:
  page=requests.get('http://www.pinterest.com'+singlePin)
  page_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
  page_element=page_soup.select('img[src]')
  image_address=page_element[0].attrs['src']

  resource=urllib.request.urlopen(image_address)
  output=open(Folder_saved+"/"+"Image"+str(n)+".jpg","wb")
  output.write(resource.read())
  output.close()

  n=n+1
```

Comment: Thanks i tried that but unfortunately it dosnt seem to work with the latest version of pinterest, i think this is due to the change from http to https